# JLayout recommended usage

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, plugin, jlayout

Inside a plugin I need to make a popup window to preview some HTML structure.
Can I use JLayout to achieve it or is there a more proper way to do it?
If JLayout is the way to do it, also would like to know how can I check if a certain Layout is being used.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can used Joomla's `renderModal` function to initiate a Bootstrap modal.

```
$name = 'myModal';
$html = '<a href="#modal-' . $name.'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">Launch modal</a>';

$modalParams = array();
$modalParams['title']  = 'Modal title';

$modalBody = '<p>Modal main text line 2</p>';
$modalBody .= '<p>Modal main text line 2</p>';

echo $html .= JHtml::_('bootstrap.renderModal', 'modal-' . $name, $modalParams, $modalBody);
```

The `$modalBody` variable should contain all of your modal content.

Here is a screenshot of the results:

[image]

Hope this helps