# JHtml::_('bootstrap.renderModal',,,); Joomla Bootstrap List of all parameters that can be used?

Tags: joomla-3.x, bootstrap, modal

First I want to thank @Lodder and @Irfan for the below code which helped out a lot. The code below will create a button that launches a native Joomla Bootstrap modal.

```
$modalTitle = 'myModal';

$modalParams = array();
$modalParams['title']  = 'Modal title';
$modalParams['height'] = '100%';
$modalParams['width']  = '100%';

$modalBody = '<p>Modal main text line 2</p>';
$modalBody .= '<p>Modal main text line 2</p>';

$html = '<a href="#modal-' . $modalTitle.'" data-toggle="modal" class="btn">Launch modal</a>';

echo $html .= JHtml::_('bootstrap.renderModal', 'modal-' . $modalTitle, $modalParams, $modalBody);
```

**My question is where can I find a complete set of the params that can be used?**

So far I figured out with help from others that there are the following parameters. I would like to create a complete list and leave it here for everyone to find.

```
['title'] // Not to be confused with $modalTitle as this defines the DOM element while ['title'] defines the title a visitor can see.
['height'] // Height of the modal
['width'] // Width of the modal
['url'] // Adds an Iframe inside the modal body this can work together with other modalBody content
['backdrop'] // true or false. Sets the dark background behind the modal
['animation'] // true or false. Allows the animation or not
['closebtn'] // true or false. Show or hide the closebtn
['keyboard'] // true or false. Allows closing the modal with the esc key
['footer'] // Optional markup for the modal footer
['bodyHeight'] // Sets the height of the body
['modalWidth'] // Another way to set the width
```

I made the question, and I am still doing research so when I find new stuff I add it here.

Tip: In some templates the heights are not being registered. For instance in Isis the admin template there will be a conflict between the `bodyHeight` and the default css attached to `.modal-body` this will require some custom css to make this work.

Sources:

- https://issues.joomla.org/tracker/joomla-cms/5087
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459647/struggling-with-the-jquery-bootstrap-version-of-joomlas-modal-window
- [JLayout recommended usage](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15125/jlayout-recommended-usage)
- https://www.techfry.com/joomla/adding-a-modal-to-joomla-component

Comment: I realise that you have a partial list and you are seeking a complete list, but it may be better for page layout if you transfer your currently known list of attributes and their usage to a [community wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/352329). This way, you give the desired answer a headstart at compiling a full list and other users will have an easier time contributing to the answer that you initiated.  If you have questions about this feature, you may ask me here in a comment or on [meta].